# Click a date to redirect to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need to make it so that if someone clicks on a date on the [Bootstrap datepicker plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), it redirects them to a page like `www.website.com/browse.php?date=DATECLICKED`.

This is my current code I'm using:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dp" data-toggle="dropdown" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">Custom Date <b class="caret"></b></a>
</li>
```

How would this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the changeDate callback to trigger the redirect.

```
$('#dp').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
    window.location.href = 'www.website.com/browse.php?date=' + ev.date.valueOf();
  });
```